# recursive buildout recipe

Tags: django, buildout

In trying to apply [Jacob Kaplan-Moss's tutorial on buildout](http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/) to my own workflow, I can't figure out how to make buildout recursive. An example of the problem I'm trying to solve:  I want my django site to consist of one repository (with a buildout.cfg) which allows for developer testing, and a second repository with configuration data (settings files, database connection dependencies, etc) which includes the first repository but with its own buildout.cfg. In the site buildout.cfg, I would like to only specify the first repository and have buildout retrieve its requirements (as specified in *its* buildout.cfg).

This would be easy if including a "development-egg" caused it's "buildout.cfg" to be incorporated, but it doesn't seem to be happening for me. As this must be a common problem, could someone point me to the solution.

Thanks. Kent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that might help you:

- Requirements should be specified in the setup.py, not in the buildout.cfg.  You *can* tell a buildout to download extra packages, but if you want to have a list of requirements that is "recursive", you need to add those requirements to the `install_requires` in Jacob's example setup.py.
- If you want to re-use bits and pieces of buildout configs, look at the `extends` option in the buildout documentation at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout .